Need to Create a List View Button that will run "QuickAction.Global.Fonteva1__NewContact"
On the Page layout of an object I have a "Mobile & Lightning Actions" for New Contact which is Fonteva1__NewContact. Unfortunately this action isn't showing as an addable button in List View layout.
I believe the best way to fix this is to create a new Button that calls that quick action but I haven't been able to find the correct way to set this up. In the Custom Button or New Action I am unable to find a way to evoke this action.
